# Add new key to array object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
const images =[
  { uri: 'images1' }, 
  { uri: 'images2' }, 
  { uri: 'images3' }, 
  { uri: 'image4' }, 

]
```

and I want to add key to each object as

```
const newimages =[
  { source: { uri: 'images1' } },
  { source: { uri: 'images2' } },
  { source: { uri: 'images3' } },
  { source: { uri: 'images4' } }
]
```

Please help me as I am new to this programming field.

Answer (score 5):

Use `.map` to transform one array into another based on its elements:

```js
const images =[
  { uri: 'images1' }, 
  { uri: 'images2' }, 
  { uri: 'images3' }, 
  { uri: 'image4' }, 
  { uri: 'images5' }, 
];
const newImages = images.map(({ uri }) => ({
  source: { uri }
}));

console.log(newImages);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a map:

```
const newimages = images.map((i) => ({ source: i }))
```

Comment: There is a logical error in your code. Have you checked it by running?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to JavaScript!
Maybe you could try using a for loop like this:

```
var images =[
  { uri: 'images1' }, 
  { uri: 'images2' }, 
  { uri: 'images3' }, 
  { uri: 'image4' }, 

];

var newImages = [];

for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
  newImages.push({
    source: images[i]
  })
}

console.log(newImages)
```